# No style only Plain text when try to login

Tags: uri

SO I have a problem when I try to login to Drupal (drupal.kalianet.to/user)it gives me a plain text with no style. I realized when I inspect the page that it automatically put user after the domain name. Which Im not sure what really the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the styles can't be loaded. Have you tried clearing the cache and saving the file-system path? Perhaps the sites/default/files folder isn't writeable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I check the folder sites/default/files and it on 0755 which I think is writeable right?

Comment: 755 would do the trick. Perhaps it's handy to post a screenshot with some logs (admin/reports/dblog).

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the reply the website is live and you check it @ drupal.kalianet.to if that easy.

Comment: user 10/25/2017 - 22:14 Session opened for admin. admin 
cron 10/25/2017 - 21:40 Cron run completed. Anonymous (not verified) 
cron 10/25/2017 - 21:40 Execution of update_cron() took 25507.74ms. Anonymous (not verified) 
cron 10/25/2017 - 21:39 Starting execution of update_cron(), execution of… Anonymous (not verified) 
cron 10/25/2017 - 21:39 Starting execution of system_cron(), execution of… Anonymous (not verified) 
cron 10/25/2017 - 21:39 Starting execution of search_cron(), execution